# Wordsearch Program In C

Tags: c

I am currently trying to write a wordsearch program in C, the program is meant to generate a 2D wordsearch and use words from 5 different categories that are preset, as well as giving the user an option to choose which category they wish to choose , so far this is the code i have but i've hit a wall and do not know where to go from here, can anyone give me any ideas?

this is my code:

```
/* ICP-1029 - Assignment 1 */
/* WordSearch Puzzle Porgram */
/* Callum Fawcett */
/* Version 1 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    const char *animalArray[20]; 

    animalArray[0] = "lynx";
    animalArray[1] = "kitten";
    animalArray[2] = "cheetah";
    animalArray[3] = "ape";
    animalArray[4] = "doe";
    animalArray[5] = "reindeer";
    animalArray[6] = "whale";
    animalArray[7] = "baboon";
    animalArray[8] = "skunk";
    animalArray[9] = "dugong";
    animalArray[10] = "elephant";
    animalArray[11] = "anteater";
    animalArray[12] = "chameleon";
    animalArray[13] = "lizaed";
    animalArray[14] = "horse";

    const char *colourArray[20];

    colourArray[0] = "red";
    colourArray[1] = "green";
    colourArray[2] = "blue";
    colourArray[3] = "black";
    colourArray[4] = "pink";
    colourArray[5] = "yellow";
    colourArray[6] = "brown";
    colourArray[7] = "orange";
    colourArray[8] = "purple";
    colourArray[9] = "black";
    colourArray[10] = "white";
    colourArray[11] = "cyan";
    colourArray[12] = "maroon";
    colourArray[13] = "magenta";
    colourArray[14] = "grey";

    const char *videogameArray[20];

    videogameArray[0] = "fortnite";
    videogameArray[1] = "fifa";
    videogameArray[2] = "hytale";
    videogameArray[3] = "soma";
    videogameArray[4] = "prey";
    videogameArray[5] = "destiny";
    videogameArray[6] = "titanfall";
    videogameArray[7] = "woldenstein";
    videogameArray[8] = "battlefield";
    videogameArray[9] = "fallout";
    videogameArray[10] = "tekken";
    videogameArray[11] = "skyrim";
    videogameArray[12] = "dishonored";
    videogameArray[13] = "uncharted";
    videogameArray[14] = "anthem";

    const char *sportsArray[20];

    sportsArray[0] = "basketball";
    sportsArray[1] = "football";
    sportsArray[2] = "cricket";
    sportsArray[3] = "wrestling";
    sportsArray[4] = "fencing";
    sportsArray[5] = "rowing";
    sportsArray[6] = "volleyball";
    sportsArray[7] = "baseball";
    sportsArray[8] = "hockey";
    sportsArray[9] = "racing";
    sportsArray[10] = "golf";
    sportsArray[11] = "bobsleigh";
    sportsArray[12] = "curling";
    sportsArray[13] = "snowboarding";
    sportsArray[14] = "bowling";

    const char *countryArray[20];

    countryArray[0] = "england";
    countryArray[1] = "ireland";
    countryArray[2] = "china";
    countryArray[3] = "wales";
    countryArray[4] = "bangladesh";
    countryArray[5] = "maldives";
    countryArray[6] = "slovenia";
    countryArray[7] = "uruguay";
    countryArray[8] = "colombia";
    countryArray[9] = "samoa";
    countryArray[10] = "jamaica";
    countryArray[11] = "malta";
    countryArray[12] = "bulgaria";
    countryArray[13] = "armenia";
    countryArray[14] = "gamnbia";
}


char **create2DArray(); //function prototype

#define WIDTH 16
#define HEIGHT 16

char **myArray; //global array

int main() {
    myArray = create2DArray();
}

//Creates a 2D array of WIDTH * HEIGHT and returns a pointer to it
char **create2DArray() {
     int i, j;
     char **array = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * WIDTH);

     for (i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
         array[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * HEIGHT);

     for (i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++)
            // array[i][j] = 65 + rand() % 25;
            array[i][j] = '.';

    return array;
}
```

Comment: Currently _create2DArray_ fills a 16x16 array of char with '.' (or random char from  A to Y in comment), but it was probably not the goal, what it the expected goal ? To have random existing words ? Note if WIDTH and HEIGHT are constant you do not need dynamic allocation and can have `char myArray[HEIGHT][WIDTH];`

Comment: @bruno The section of code that fills the 2D array was given to me by my tutor, the aim is to fill the wordsearch with random letters along with words from the 5 categories that i had already set, however i dont think that i have done this correctly as when i compile my program i get errors about having two main methods and when i try to run it nothing happens.

Comment: All is 2D array so difficult to separate them ;-) Do you want _myArray_ filled with words randomly coming from the other arrays ?

Comment: @bruno yeah thats how i wanted it to go

Comment: I put an answer but I am not sure this is what you want, it is *very* difficult to understand what you want

Comment: what im trying to do is create a wordsearch program that allows the user to choose from 5 different subjects, the program then creates a 2D array filled with random letters and 6 random words from the chosen category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proposal,   words can be placed horizontally (left to right) , vertically (top to bottom), in diagonal always left to right but top to bottom or bottom to top

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define WIDTH 16
#define HEIGHT 16
#define NWORDS 6

char wordsearch[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

/* horizontaly */

int canPlaceH(const char * word, int i, int j)
{
  if ((strlen(word) + j) > WIDTH)
    return 0;

  do {
    if ((wordsearch[i][j] != 0) && (wordsearch[i][j] != *word))
      return 0;
    j += 1;
  } while (*++word);

  return 1;
}

void placeH(const char * word, int i, int j)
{
  do {
    wordsearch[i][j++] = *word;
  }  while (*++word);
}

/* verticaly */

int canPlaceV(const char * word, int i, int j)
{
  if ((strlen(word) + i) > HEIGHT)
    return 0;

  do {
    if ((wordsearch[i][j] != 0) && (wordsearch[i][j] != *word))
      return 0;
    i += 1;
  } while (*++word);

  return 1;
}

void placeV(const char * word, int i, int j)
{
  do {
    wordsearch[i++][j] = *word;
  }  while (*++word);
}

/* diagonal up */

int canPlaceDU(const char * word, int i, int j)
{
  int ln = strlen(word);

  if (((ln + j) > WIDTH) || ((i - ln) < 0))
    return 0;

  do {
    if ((wordsearch[i][j] != 0) && (wordsearch[i][j] != *word))
      return 0;
    i -= 1;
    j += 1;
  } while (*++word);

  return 1;
}

void placeDU(const char * word, int i, int j)
{
  do {
    wordsearch[i--][j++] = *word;
  }  while (*++word);
}

/* diagonal down */

int canPlaceDD(const char * word, int i, int j)
{
  int ln = strlen(word);

  if (((ln + j) > WIDTH) || ((i + ln) > HEIGHT))
    return 0;

  do {
    if ((wordsearch[i][j] != 0) && (wordsearch[i][j] != *word))
      return 0;
    i += 1;
    j += 1;
  } while (*++word);

  return 1;
}

void placeDD(const char * word, int i, int j)
{
  do {
    wordsearch[i++][j++] = *word;
  }  while (*++word);
}

void fillWordsearch(const char ** a, int sz)
{
  /* first step add words from a */
  const char * used[NWORDS - 1] = { NULL }; /* to not get two times the same word */

  for (int w = 0; w != NWORDS; ++w) {
    /* random choice of a word not yet used */
    const char * word;

    for (;;) {
      word = a[rand() % sz];
      int i;

      /* check not yet used */
      for (i = 0; i != w; ++i)
        if (!strcmp(used[i], word))
          break;

      if (i == w) {
        /* not yet used */
        used[w] = word;
        break;
      }
    }

    /* random placement */

    int i, j, d;
    typedef int (*canFunc)(const char *, int, int);
    typedef void (*placeFunc)(const char *, int, int);
    const canFunc canPlace[] = { canPlaceH, canPlaceV, canPlaceDU, canPlaceDD };
    const placeFunc place[] = { placeH, placeV, placeDU, placeDD };

    do {
      i = rand() % HEIGHT;
      j = rand() % WIDTH;
      d = rand() % 4;
    } while (!(*canPlace[d])(word, i, j));
    (*place[d])(word, i, j);

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("place %s on %d %d direction %d\n", word, i, j, d);
#endif
  }

#ifdef DEBUG
  for (int i = 0; i != HEIGHT; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j != WIDTH; ++j)
      putchar((wordsearch[i][j] == 0) ? '.' : wordsearch[i][j]);
    putchar('\n');
  }
  putchar('\n');
#endif

  /* second step fill not yet set characters with random lowercase letters */
  int i,j;

  for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
    for (j = 0; j != WIDTH; ++j)
      if (wordsearch[i][j] == 0)
        wordsearch[i][j] = 'a' + rand() % ('z' - 'a' + 1);
}

int main()
{
  const char *animalArray[] = {
    "lynx",
    "kitten",
    "cheetah",
    "ape",
    "doe",
    "reindeer",
    "whale",
    "baboon",
    "skunk",
    "dugong",
    "elephant",
    "anteater",
    "chameleon",
    "lizaed",
    "horse"
  };

  const char *colourArray[] = {
    "red",
    "green",
    "blue",
    "black",
    "pink",
    "yellow",
    "brown",
    "orange",
    "purple",
    "black",
    "white",
    "cyan",
    "maroon",
    "magenta",
    "grey"
  };

  const char *videogameArray[] = {
    "fortnite",
    "fifa",
    "hytale",
    "soma",
    "prey",
    "destiny",
    "titanfall",
    "woldenstein",
    "battlefield",
    "fallout",
    "tekken",
    "skyrim",
    "dishonored",
    "uncharted",
    "anthem"
  };

  const char *sportsArray[] = {
    "basketball",
    "football",
    "cricket",
    "wrestling",
    "fencing",
    "rowing",
    "volleyball",
    "baseball",
    "hockey",
    "racing",
    "golf",
    "bobsleigh",
    "curling",
    "snowboarding",
    "bowling"
  };

  const char *countryArray[] = {
    "england",
    "ireland",
    "china",
    "wales",
    "bangladesh",
    "maldives",
    "slovenia",
    "uruguay",
    "colombia",
    "samoa",
    "jamaica",
    "malta",
    "bulgaria",
    "armenia",
    "gamnbia"
  };

  printf("choose category 1=animal 2=colour 3=video-game 4=sport 5=country : ");

  int i;

  if ((scanf("%d", &i) != 1) || (i < 1) || (i > 5))
    return -1;

  srand(time(NULL));

  switch (i) {
  case 1:
    fillWordsearch(animalArray, sizeof(animalArray)/sizeof(*animalArray));
    break;
  case 2:
    fillWordsearch(colourArray, sizeof(colourArray)/sizeof(*colourArray));
    break;
  case 3:
    fillWordsearch(videogameArray, sizeof(videogameArray)/sizeof(*videogameArray));
    break;
  case 4:
    fillWordsearch(sportsArray, sizeof(sportsArray)/sizeof(*sportsArray));
    break;
  default:
    fillWordsearch(countryArray, sizeof(countryArray)/sizeof(*countryArray));
    break;
  }

  /* print result */
  for (i = 0; i != HEIGHT; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j != WIDTH; ++j)
      putchar(wordsearch[i][j]);
    putchar('\n');
  }

  return 0;
}
```

When compiling with DEBUG defined that indicates which word is placed and how and also prints the wordsearch with only the inserted words.

Compilation and some executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -DDEBUG -g c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
choose category 1=animal 2=colour 3=video-game 4=sport 5=country : 1
place skunk on 14 10 direction 0
place elephant on 0 15 direction 1
place lizaed on 6 11 direction 1
place cheetah on 13 2 direction 0
place chameleon on 4 3 direction 0
place horse on 12 3 direction 0
...............e
...............l
...............e
...............p
...chameleon...h
...............a
...........l...n
...........i...t
...........z....
...........a....
...........e....
...........d....
...horse........
..cheetah.......
..........skunk.
................

xjzcgwbnnxlmaaje
wgssltuqwsuozgjl
ldtmfzijoxizmkze
vgipavkvmhnixmpp
hzuchameleonalah
bvlpuvqggpdoztpa
vdkjmzrklirlmdrn
zfswqjqnzxtiqait
qvzlzjwlinvzvymj
bfigzgyiwlhatfyw
pqrodqzzejoezgmo
rnvbvvhtddfdnzmn
vbdhorsemrgfshjd
vkcheetahjkaczwd
vrkowptjofskunkw
jibybjdvqoyoyjyb
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
choose category 1=animal 2=colour 3=video-game 4=sport 5=country : 2
place brown on 6 0 direction 1
place magenta on 12 5 direction 2
place yellow on 8 4 direction 3
place grey on 13 12 direction 0
place pink on 6 8 direction 3
place black on 5 11 direction 2
................
...............k
..............c.
.............a..
............l...
...........b....
b.......p..a....
r........it.....
o...y....nn.....
w....e..e..k....
n.....lg........
......al........
.....m..o.......
.........w..grey
................
................

syxxaavuzbbvskbu
lcmcvehexwrvkylk
cyizyixuiyxfshcg
mtkaxfhelecdbamd
mqcuscfpzppyluhg
cvbmyathgflbikmx
bpantwfwpbwaxsnv
rmudosgcqitgwzod
okznyywcynnlwutu
wyrtqefoefbkuvta
nyljuklgxxwymwuo
uimrbialrsbjxsoz
mmuokmizoeuzdtxp
psfmasddawwvgrey
efvwwwiisysayyxx
dqusfoxrqrwtusry
```

Comment: does this place them into my wordsearch?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=wordsearch&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIiur7tr7hAhXwXhUIHSmpCbcQ_AUIDigB&biw=1093&bih=622#imgrc=aWf2bUlvOeXugM:   --  this is a wordsearch

Comment: ah ok. @CallumFawcett damned why you did not put that link in your question since the beginning to make it clear ? words can be written horizontal or vertical I supose ?

Comment: @sorry i thought wordsearch was well known, and yes they can be horizontal, vertical or diagonal.

Comment: @CallumFawcett what do you want, some hints to help you to do it, or the code ? ;-)

Comment: I have a basic knowledge of c, however I need to finish this ASAP, I will learn from reading your code

Comment: I have a basic knowledge of c, however I need to finish this ASAP, I will learn from reading your code

Comment: @CallumFawcett I did, and I am afraid you have just your solution but not sure you will really learn something :-( I mainly did for the fun ^^

Comment: one more question before you go, is there a way to remove the part where it tells you where the words have been placed x

Comment: @CallumFawcett  frankly if you are not able to find you do not deserve that solution, this is **trivial** Did you at least read my answer ?

Comment: don’t worry about it I’ll find it

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtile problem in your first `main` function:

You define arrays of 20 string pointers and only initialize the first 15 entries in them. The remaining entries are not initialized, they do not have a null pointer. You should probably write this instead:

```
    const char *animalArray[20] = {
        "lynx", "kitten", "cheetah", "ape", "doe",
        "reindeer", "whale", "baboon", "skunk", "dugong",
        "elephant", "anteater", "chameleon", "lizaed", "horse",
    };
```

Regarding you `create2DArray` function:

- you should probably transpose `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH`: it would be more consistent to have an array of `HEIGHT` rows of `WITDH` characters.
- you could allocate a real 2D array this way:

  ```
  int main() {
      // local array
      char (*myArray)[WIDTH] = malloc(sizeof(*array) * HEIGHT);
      for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
          for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
              myArray[i][j] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[rand() % 26];
      }
  }
  ```

  Or you could just define the array as `char myArray[HEIGHT][WIDTH];`

Beyond these remarks, your question is unclear. You might want to clarify your goal and your constraints.

Comment: Thank you for this help, my main issue is that my code doesnt generate the wordsearch and i do not know how to put the 5 arrays into the wordsearch either